# SQL - List from a Start and End Series

Tags: sql, ssms, series

I have a table that has a reporting item series like so:

```
Reporting Name  Starting Number         Ending Number
AW              965845                  -
GRT             6700                    6705
QEF             2011                    -
```

I am hoping to output the following table below in Access preferably but I can translate from SQL to Access if need be.

```
Output:

Combined Ref
AW 965845
GRT 6700
GRT 6701
GRT 6702
GRT 6703
GRT 6704
GRT 6705
QEF 2011
```

Can you please help me?

Comment: @attila Okay so I was afraid of an answer like that... so what about a solution in SQL that takes the reporting item series and creates the possible combinations for Access that looks like the Output.

Answer (score 1):

The only way I would know how to do this in Access is to use a tally table. This table would contain all of the possible numbers you would need, 1 through ?

```
create table tallynumbers (nbrs INTEGER)
```

You could pretty easily load this via Excel.

Then you can just join like this:

```
select ReportingName, nbr
from reporting_items as ri, tallynumbers as tn
where tn.nbr between ri.[Starting Number] and iif(IsNull(ri.[Ending Number]),ri.[Starting Number],ri.[Ending Number])
```

**UPDATE**
If you can do all of this in SQL Server 2005+, here is another option for you

Here is the reports table

```
create table reports (ReportingName varchar(10), StartingNumber int, EndingNumber int)
```

Now fill it with your sample values

```
insert into reports
values ('AW', 965845, null),
('GRT', 6700, 6705),
('QEF', 2011, null)
```

Now for the recursive CTE to get it into the format you want

```
;with RecurReports
as
(

  select ReportingName, StartingNumber as nbr, 
     coalesce(EndingNumber,startingnumber) as enbr
  from reports
  union all select rr.ReportingName, nbr +1, enbr
  from reports r 
  inner join RecurReports rr 
     on r.ReportingName=rr.ReportingName
  where nbr < enbr
)
select ReportingName, nbr as Number from RecurReports
```

Here is the SQL Fiddle: http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!6/91137/1

Comment: I agree with this answer.  in SQL server or other platforms you could use ROWNUMBER or an autoincrementing temp table, but with Access you are severely limited.

Comment: @attila Okay so I was afraid of an answer like that... so what about a solution in SQL that takes the reporting item series and creates the possible combinations for Access that looks like the Output. (not sure where to post to get your attention).

Comment: This is the correct place to get my attention. If you were using SQL Server 2005+, I would recommend using a recursive CTE to build your "tally table" and then join to that to get your numbers between start and end. Access, as far as I know, doesn't have a better way of getting your output other than what I posted. Don't be afraid of tally tables. They are used frequently for numbers and dates. Here is a link about them - http://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/T-SQL/62867/

Comment: @attila What I was thinking is create the specific tally table after importing to SQL the begin and end series I need then send that tally table over the business user that needs it to work in Access.

Comment: Are you looking to be able to output your result to Access? Does this mean you can do the processing in SQL Server? If so, then a recursive CTE would be an option, instead of a tally table.

Comment: I updated the answer with an option for a recursive CTE and no tally table. This assumes SQL Server 2005+.